# How to run multiple SQL query "load local infile" in PowerShell?

Tags: sql, powershell

I am preparing a script to "load data local infile" using PowerShell. Which I will install on the task schedule, how do I use the "load data local infile" on the PowerShell & I need to load more than one data ??

Comment: Please read the help about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit the question filling in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -h $dbhost -u $dbusername -p $dbpassword -D $dbname  -e " ` 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/My_PC/Downloads/file_1.csv' `
IGNORE INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES; `
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/My_PC/Downloads/file_2.csv' `
IGNORE INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES; `
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/My_PC/Downloads/file_3.csv' `
IGNORE INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES; "
```